# Azure B2C: Email address not available as application claim and also missing in claims result

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am configuring an Azure B2C instance and created a signupsignin *userflow*. Selecting "Display Name" and "Email Address" as *User attributes* I expected that it was possible to add those two attributes also as *Application claims* but "Email Address" is not a default option, only "Email Addresses". Even with that option on, when testing the userflow I can't see the "Email address" included as a claim. How do I have to configure Azure B2C using userflow (not custom policy) and getting the email address back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

In my B2C tenant, I created one **Sign up and sign in** user flow by enabling **`emails`** in return claim as below:

[image]

I created one B2C application and selected it while **running user flow** like below:

[image]

When I ran the user flow, it displayed sign in screen with **email address** as below:

[image]

If the user signs in **successfully**, they will get **`code`** in their address bar along with **redirect Uri** like this:

[image]

I used the above **`code`** to generate token via **Postman** like below:

```json
POST https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: AppID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid
client_secret: client_secret
code: //copy the code you got above
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I **decoded** this token, I got **`emails`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

If you are not using **`Email sign-up`** method, make sure to update user's profile by adding **email** before running user flow like below:

[image]